# x.split has no effect

Tags: python, arrays

For some reason `x.split(':', 1)[-1]` doesn't do anything. Could someone explain and maybe help me?

I'm trying to remove the data before : (including ":") but it keeps that data anyway

**Code**

```
data = { 'state': 1, 'endTime': 1518852709307, 'fileSize': 000000 }
data = data.strip('{}')
data = data.split(',')
for x in data:
    x.split(':', 1)[-1]
    print(x)`
```

**Output**

```
"state":1
"endTime":1518852709307
"fileSize":16777216
```

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)?

Comment: `split` doesn't mutate (change) `x`.  It returns the result, which you should capture in a variable `x = x.split(':', 1)[-1]`

Comment: thank you @PatrickHaugh it was a silly mistake i made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a dictonary, not a list of strings.
I think this is what you're looking for:

```
data = str({"state":1,"endTime":1518852709307,"fileSize":000000}) #add a str() here
data = data.strip('{}')
data = data.split(',')
for x in data:
   x=x.split(':')[-1] # set x to x.split(...)
   print(x)
```

The script below prints out:

```
 1
 1518852709307
 0
```

Here is a one-liner version:

```
print (list(map(lambda x:x[1],data.items())))
```

Prints out:

```
[1, 1518852709307, 0]
```

Which is a list of integers.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just want the values in the dictionary

```
data = {"state":1,"endTime":1518852709307,"fileSize":000000}
for x in data:
   print(data[x])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think it's because the computer treats "state" and 1 as separate objects. Therefore, it is merely stripping the string "state" of its colons, of which there are none.

You could make the entire dictionary into a string by putting:

```
data = str({ Your Dictionary Here })
```

then, print what you have left in for "for x in data" statement like so:

```
for x in data:
   b = x.split(':', 1)[-1]  # creating a new string 
   print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

`data` in your code is a dictionary. So you can just access your the values of it like `data[state]` which evaluates to `1`.

If you get this data as a string like:
    data = "{'state':1, 'endTime':1518852709307, 'fileSize':000000}"

You could use `json.loads` to convert it into a dictionary and access the data like explained above.

```
import json
data = '{"state":1, "endTime":1518852709307, "fileSize":0}'
data = json.loads(data)
for _,v in data.items():
   print(v)
```

If you want to parse the string yourself this should work:

```
data = '{"state":1,"endTime":1518852709307,"fileSize":000000}'
data = data.strip('{}')
data = data.split(',')
for x in data:
    x=x.split(':')[-1]
    print(x)
```